# Error code in jquery-3.0.0.min.js

Tags: jquery, signalr, jquery-3

I'm not sure it's an error, but when I tried to change the version `3.0.0` to version `2.2.3`, it's working fine.

I'm making a demo with signalr, like this:

In the html:

```
<button>Click me</button>
// <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

In `app.js`:

```
var hub = $.connection.hub;
var chat = $.connection.chat;

hub.start().done(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        chat.server.sayHello('Hermione').done(function (msg) {
            alert(msg)
        });
    });
});
```

In the Hub:

```
public string SayHello(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

Here is the error snapshot when I tried to use jquery version `3.0.0`:

[image: 1]

Error messages:

> Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
>
> Uncaught Error: SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.

My question: what's happen with the jquery version `3.0.0` in this case?

Comment: Having you included the jquery 3.0 migration plugin?  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#migrate-older-jquery-code-to-jquery-30

Comment: @freedomn-m Following your advice, I've added `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js` to the page and it works. Thanks!

Comment: My typo aside, my point was that the plugin should tell you what's changed, not cover up the changes for you - check the console.log - you (and your users) will get warnings about obsolete methods on every call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) plug-in, [jQuery v3.0.0 is apparently unsupported](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3710). The plug-in documentation does not seem to provide any information about dependencies but [examples in wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections) load jQuery 1.7.

You simply cannot blame the jQuery team for that: they provide detailed release notes, migration guides and even a helper plugin. If you aren't sure that your code will work with newer releases, you shouldn't upgrade :-)

Answer (score 5):

Just replace e.load with $ in your signalr file "jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"

Comment: Not ideal to update the jQuery file - using a supported version is a better answer - but this does work.

Comment: Still an issue in signalR 2.2.3 - This hack fixed it.